# Why the margin collapses when clearance exists?

Tags: css, margin

the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins) state that:

> The bottom margin of an in-flow block-level element always collapses with the top margin of its next in-flow block-level sibling, unless that sibling has clearance.

But I found something unexpected.the [code](https://jsfiddle.net/weapon1991/Laodj8gy/) is as follows.

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 100px; "></div>
<div style="float:left;width:10px;height: 10px; background: red"></div>
<div style="margin: 100px;clear: left"></div>
test
```

the bottom margin of first `div` and the margin of the third `div` collapse, which violates 'unless that sibling has clearance'.

How to explain the situation? Can u give me some concrete example to explain the rule above more accurately?

Comment: *"the bottom margin of first div and the margin of the third div collapse, ,,,"* || On Chrome they don't collapse, what browser are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The question premise is incorrect. For all scenarios bar one, the margins do not collapse.

The simplest case is for Chrome, where in the example given, the third element *does* have clearance, the bottom-margin of the first div does not collapse with the margins of the third div, and the computed clearance is -90px. So the top of the third box is at 100px + 100px - 90px = 110px from the top of the container.

This calculation is described in Example 2 in the CSS 2.2 Spec for the `clear` property.

Similarly, in Firefox or Edge, if the example is preceded by some content, or even if the body simply has a top border, then the margins do not collapse and the clearance is -90px;

The exceptional cases are in Firefox and Edge when there is no preceding content or top border to body. In this case, Edge does not collapse the margins and computes the clearance to 0. Firefox does collapse the margins.

Comment: If the third div's 'clear' property is 'none',the top border edge of the third div is pushed to the right of the floated element. how to understand '**past**' in this [case](https://jsfiddle.net/weapon1991/6ducphav/)?